# MacBook Pro M1 USB Type-C Power Charging every time first charging will be 8W need to replug then will be changed to 86W

Tags: charging, apple-silicon

[image: Model]

What is the issue? Is it the power adaptor issue or the MacBook Pro M1 issue.

First time plug in with Apple MacBook Pro 15 2018 Original Type-C Charge 86W.
It only show 8W charging.

[image: 8W Charging]

After replug and it will show 86W charging.
[image: 86W Charging]

I have a [video](https://www.veed.io/view/d706e368-069c-4f57-927b-ebeaa1f8d60a?sharingWidget=true&panel=share) of this.

Comment: It sounds like there is a problem with the negotiation of power delivery.  Take your MacBook into an Apple store or similar retailer and ask to plug in to test to see if you need a new adapter (they should accommodate you). If it works fine there, it’s your adapter.  If not, your MacBook needs to be taken in for service.

Comment: Alternatively, if you have a friend or colleague with another MacBook, plug in this charger and check.  If the problem persists, it’s the charger.  If not, it’s your MacBook

Comment: Ok, thanks @Allan. The M1 just got it 2 weeks ago, but the adaptor for 4 years.

Comment: If the MacBook Pro is that new, why are you using such an old charger?  You should have the charger it came with.  Can you use that one to test out with?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 it is original MacBook Pro 15 inch power adaptor. I was in the rush to travel, so i only bring 1 adaptor for 2 MacBook Pro for migration. I am thinking both is from Apple should be supported. But when I found that M1 charging is so slow then I only found out only 8W.

Comment: Confirm it is the old adaptor issue, I used the new adaptor it is working fine. I also notice the old adaptor it is missing the serial no. Somehow it is broken.